# PGSQL query to get a list of sequential dates from today

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having an calendar table where I have added the list of dates on which no action should be performed.
The table is as follows and the date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
date        
2021-01-01  
2021-04-05
2021-04-06
2021-04-07  
2021-08-10
2021-11-22
2021-11-23
2021-11-24
2021-12-25
2021-12-31
```

Considering today is `2021-11-24`.
The expected output is

```
date
2021-11-24
2021-11-23
2021-11-22
```

And Considering today is `2021-12-25`
then the expected output is

```
date
2021-12-25
```

And Considering today is `2021-12-27`
then the output should contain no data.

```
date
```

It should get me the sequence with today's date in descending order without a break of sequence.
I searched on various posts I did find some of the posts related to my question but the query was little complex with nested subqueries. Is there a way to achieve the output in a more optimized way. I am new to pgsql.

Comment: Your expected output sample does not match you definition of what you want which is `date <= 2021-11-24::date`.

Comment: I have added more scenarios of the input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Create example table:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (d date); 
INSERT INTO calendar VALUES ('2021-11-23'),('2021-11-20');
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT CURRENT_DATE - '1 day'::interval * generate_series(0,10) AS d) a
LEFT JOIN calendar c ON (c.d=a.d);

          a.d        |  c.d
---------------------+------------
 2021-11-14 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-15 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-16 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-17 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-18 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-19 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-20 00:00:00 | 2021-11-20
 2021-11-21 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-22 00:00:00 | Null
 2021-11-23 00:00:00 | 2021-11-23
 2021-11-24 00:00:00 | Null
```

Subquery "a" generates a date series, and then we join it to the table.

You can add conditions , for example "WHERE calendar.d IS NULL", or "IS NOT NULL" depending on the filtering you want.

Comment: I initially understood that it's about last 3 **unbooked** dates and then realised it's about all **booked** dates among the last 3 - so I appreciate that your solution can be made to serve both cases. I wondered however, that for unbooked dates case you'd have to keep modifying upper range bound if everything is booked for the last N days - 10 in your case. If the closest unbooked date is 12 days ago, your example would find 0 unbooked dates unless you bumped up 10 to 13 in `generate_series(0,13)` - at which point you're the one doing the search, not the database.

Comment: So I was pleased to find out that PostgreSQL can happily deal with an infinite `with recursive` if you just use a limit when selecting:
`WITH RECURSIVE available_dates("date") AS ( VALUES ('today'::date) UNION ALL SELECT ("date"-'1 day'::interval)::date FROM available_dates WHERE "date" > '-infinity' ) SELECT "date" FROM available_dates where "date" not in (select "date" from maintenance_dates) limit 3;`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter by a date range, building it by subtracting 2 days from today:

```
select  "date" 
from    maintenance_dates_70099898 
where   "date" <= now()::date --you want to see today and 2 days prior; Last 3 days total
and     "date" >= now()::date - '2 days'::interval
order by 1 desc;
```

With a runnable test:

```
drop table if exists maintenance_dates_70099898;
create table maintenance_dates_70099898 ("date" date);
insert into maintenance_dates_70099898 
    ("date")
values 
    ('2021-01-01'),
    ('2021-04-05'),
    ('2021-04-06'),
    ('2021-04-07'),
    ('2021-08-10'),
    ('2021-11-22'),
    ('2021-11-23'),
    ('2021-11-24'),
    ('2021-12-25'),
    ('2021-12-31');

select  "date" 
from    maintenance_dates_70099898 
where   "date" <= now()::date --you want to see today and 2 days prior; Last 3 days total
and     "date" >= now()::date - '2 days'::interval
order by 1 desc;
--    date
--------------
-- 2021-11-24
-- 2021-11-23
-- 2021-11-22
--(3 rows)

select  "date" 
from    maintenance_dates_70099898 
where   "date" >= '2021-12-25'::date - '2 days'::interval 
and     "date" <= '2021-12-25'::date
order by 1 desc;
--    date
--------------
-- 2021-12-25
--(1 row)
```

I assume that for 2021-12-27 you do want to see 2021-12-25, as it's within the 3 day range prior.

```
select  "date" 
from    maintenance_dates_70099898 
where   "date" >= '2021-12-28'::date - '2 days'::interval 
and     "date" <= '2021-12-28'::date
order by 1 desc;
-- date
--------
--(0 rows)
```

Comment: the prior number of days range is not fixed.

Comment: @sheetaldharerao Then you need to edit the question to specify where you keep the date range or what it depends on. Also, please correct the expected output as it currently does not match your definition (the 2021-12-27 case that should return 2021-12-25 which is within 3 days prior, but you expect it not to).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue appears to be not having a known number of days thus disabling a simple range validation/selection. However to the rescue there is a [RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html) cte to pluck off each previous date that is exactly 1 day prior to the last and terminate when no longer holds.

```
with recursive no_action(no_act_dt) as
     ( select no_act_dt 
         from no_action_calendar
        where no_act_dt = :parm_date::date
       union all 
       select c.no_act_dt 
         from no_action_calendar  c 
         join no_action           a 
           on (c.no_act_dt = a.no_act_dt - 1)
     )
select * 
  from no_action
 order by no_act_dt desc;
```

If you use this often or from several points, you can parametrize it with a SQL function. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4a655c6b2b3990382cc4a182ab9a62ff) for both).

```
create or replace 
function consective_no_action_dates (date_in date)
 returns setof date
language sql 
as $$
    with recursive no_action(no_act_dt) as
         ( select no_act_dt 
             from no_action_calendar
            where no_act_dt = date_in
           union all 
           select c.no_act_dt 
             from no_action_calendar  c 
             join no_action           a 
               on (c.no_act_dt = a.no_act_dt - 1)
         )
    select * 
      from no_action
     order by no_act_dt desc;
$$;
```